# Pass value to Laravel database placeholder

Tags: postgresql, laravel, laravel-4

How would I express this syntax using Laravel's database?

```
SELECT ident FROM delete_team WHERE modified > to_timestamp(?)
```

I'm not sure how to pass the value for the to_timestamp placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DB::select`:

```
DB::select('SELECT ident FROM delete_team WHERE modified > to_timestamp(?)', array($value));
```

Using Query Builder:

```
DB::table('delete_team')
    ->select('ident')
    ->whereRaw('modified > to_timestamp(?)', array($value)))
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
DB::select('SELECT ident FROM delete_team WHERE modified > ?', array(DB::raw("to_timestamp($value)"));
```

Comment: That would open me up to an injection attack, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Gargoyle `DB::raw` itself yes, but it passed to the rest of query as parameter so it should be handled correctly but I'm not sure